# Angular+Bootstrap stacking clickable areas

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

In my angular app, I have objects that I'm getting from a REST API that I'm making into columns in a grid, sort of like an image gallery type thing.

Example:

[image]

The intent was for the entire grey area to be clickable, which opens a Details View modal.  Then when you hit the Delete button, it opens a Delete Item modal.  Both modals are opened with angular's ng-click.

However, since they are both in the same container (the grey, clickable one), whenever I click the Delete button, it opens up both modals instead of just the Delete Item one.

Is there any way to fix that, ala forcing the button to be in the 'front', such that clicking it will only open the correct modal?

Thanks!

Edit:  The html looks something like this -

```
<div class="row">
  <div ng-repeat="item in items" class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="item-container" ng-click="openDetailModal(item)">
     <!--stuff-->
     <button class="btn btn-danger pull-right" ng-click="openDeleteItemModal(item) />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can hide detail modal when you click on delete button.

Comment: Check for the target to see the element that fired the click event on the onClick function